# zsh: no such file or directory: - but file exists

Tags: awk, zsh, dirname

Background: I already have a working alias `my-tool` as follows:

```bash
alias my-tool='~/path/to/src/my-tool.py'
```

I want another alias that depends on that alias' path (so I don't write the path in two places):

```bash
alias other-tool=$'$(dirname $(dirname $(which my-tool | awk \'{ print($NF) }\')))/script/other-tool.sh'
```

which outputs the error

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ~/path/to/script/other-tool.sh
```

but it exists!

Strangely, if I replace the alias with

```bash
alias other-tool=$'$(dirname $(dirname ~/path/to/src/my-tool.py))/script/other-tool.sh'
```

it works, but again I want to avoid entering the `~/path/to/..` twice

Clearly there's unexpected behavior in either `awk`, `dirname` or `which`, can anyone explain why the error?

Comment: The output of this piece is different from what you expect: `which my-tool | awk \'{ print($NF) }\'` ?

Comment: No, it is as expected, and the path or file it says doesn't exist in the error output certainly does.  That's the part that's the mystery

Comment: I would create an environment variable like: `export MYDIR=~/path/to/src`, and use `$MYDIR` in all scripts that need it.  (But, of course, with a better name than `MYDIR` )

Comment: That works and I'm implementing it, thanks.  This is just a mystery/annoyance

Comment: I would expect that you do not  have a directory named `~`.  In some contexts, `~` is expanded to the path of your home directory, but in others it is not.  Always replace `~` with `$HOME`.  Tilde should only be used interactively, so you do not have to worry about the details of when tilde expansions are applied.

Comment: @OliverWilliams Regarding the first 2 comments above, given the example value of `my-tool` in your question, `'~/path/to/src/my-tool.py'`, if `~` expands to a path that includes spaces the output of `which my-tool | awk '{ print($NF) }'` would be everything between the 1st 2 spaces, otherwise it'd be a null string. Either way, it's hard to believe that'd be the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

There's a tilde character at the beginning of the alias. This works when the alias is invoked as a command, because the result of the alias expansion undergoes word expansion. But then you attempt to do some processing on the text of the alias, which results in a string that you want to use as a path. That string still contains a tilde character, so you're attempting to use a directory called `~`.

If you really want to use the `my-tool` alias as a basis for defining the `other-tool` alias, do the string processing at the time you define the alias. Don't use `type` or `which`: they're end-user commands that display additional messages. Reach directly for the text of the alias, using the [`aliases` associative array](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-aliases). Use zsh's built-in constructs for manipulating strings ([parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)) or paths ([history modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)): they're easier to get right than using external tools.

```
alias other-tool=$aliases[my-tool]:h:h/scripts/other-tool.sh
```

or

```
alias other-tool=${aliases[my-tool]%/*/*}/scripts/other-tool.sh
```

But it would be both conceptually simpler and more reliable to instead define a variable with the root path, and use that variable in both aliases.

```
tool_root=~/path/to
alias my-tool='$tool_root/src/my-tool.py'
alias other-tool='$tool_root/scripts/other-tool.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely better ways to do this (I like the path prefix variable mentioned by @Luuk in a comment), but a working equivalent to what you're trying is:

```bash
alias other-tool=$'loc=($(type my-tool)); ${~loc[-1]:h:h}/script/other-tool.sh'
```

Instead of running `awk` and a couple of `dirname` processes each time you run the alias, this uses `zsh` parameter substutitions intead - first it sets the `loc` array variable to the result of running `type my-tool`, with each word its own element, then for the last element (The path): The `:h` modifier acts like `dirname`, done twice, and then the `~` turns on the `GLOB_SUBST` option for that expansion, which among other things does filename expansion, catching the `~`.

Comment: If you have spaces in the path, this will break, but there's ways to work around it if needed.

Answer (score -1):

the way i deal with tilde (`~`) is simply expand it out once instead of hard-quoting them with single quotes (`'`)- this way i wouldn't have to go manually replace it with `"${HOME}"` :

```
testfn="$( grealpath -ePq ~/.zshenv )"   # g- for gnu

echo "${testfn}"
ls -AlF "${testfn}"

/Users/user123/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 user123  staff  1746187 Aug 27 23:54 /Users/user123/.bash_profile
```

And that's actually a correct output, since my `zsh` environment file is actually a symlink :

```
lr--r--r--  1 user123  staff  15 Dec 31  2019 /Users/user123/.zshenv -> ./.bash_profile
```